# Alternative way for title to display html tags(<br>,etc, <img>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem which is:

I'm using this Javascript code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
        // Hover out code
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});
```

with:

```
echo "<img class='masterTooltip' title='Desc: <br> $xxx' id='xxx' width='50px' src='xx'/>";
```

But it shows [br] as [br] not breaking into a new line, I need an alternative way for using [p],[br],etc.

I know It can't be done within title attribute, but I'm not so experienced with javascript,

So any help would be greatly appericiated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is the `echo` statement supposed to mean? If the technology used to generate an HTML document is essential, tag the question with its name; if not, show just the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.text(title)` by `.html(title)`. This causes the value of the variable `title` to be parsed as HTML, instead of being taken as plain text.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .html(title)    // THIS WAS CHANGED
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
        // Hover out code
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='masterTooltip' title='Desc: <br> $xxx' id='xxx' width='50px' src='http://lorempixel.com/50/50/'/>
```